# React-google-chart throws Content Security Policy issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script

React-google-chart works well in development but it throws below error after build deployed in server.

```
VM565 2.351f67d9.chunk.js:2 Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have tried

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"` in manifest file

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ws: ;
    style-src 'self' https: *.google-analytics.com;
    script-src 'self' https: *.google-analytics.com;
    media-src 'none';
    font-src *;
    connect-src *;
    img-src 'self' data: content: https: *.google-analytics.com;">
```

in index.html file

but none worked. May i know what i missing ? thanks